# How to change the date type in a Oracle Select?

Tags: oracle, types

I'm usualy use PostgreSQL, but I'm currently doing it in Oracle.

I need to chage the data type of a column in a query(select), in PostgreSQL I usualy do it in this way:

```
select 1::varchar from table
```

Hoe can I do this in Oracle?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

convert to varchar

```
 select to_char(Field) from table
```

truncate varchar

```
 select substr(field, 1, 1) from table
```

Comment: It's almost always better to specify an explicit format (e.g. `to_char(column, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`) when using to_char() to avoid different (unexpected) results depending on NLS settings

Answer (score 4):

As @Michael Pakhantsov points out, `to_char` works for converting to string.  Likewise, `to_date` and `to_timestamp` are the standard when converting strings to dates and timestamps respectively.  However, if you find that you need to perform a more exotic conversion (varchar2 to raw, for instance), then `cast` is your friend:

Number to string:

```
select cast(field as varchar2(30)) from table;
```

String to Raw:

```
select cast(field as raw(16)) from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @Allan I like to use `cast()`, as it can go from and to many types.
However, as the official documentation says,

> CAST does not support LONG, LONG RAW, any of the LOB datatypes, or the Oracle-supplied types

So it cannot be used to convert to CLOB, for example, Oracle will throw

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I agree it reads better. I'm new here so still getting used to the formatting tools.